# Contacting old honours advisor

Tags: etiquette

First a brief explanation (I'm not sure if other schools have different systems): at my university, if one took the correct courses during their degree - pure math in my case - then one had the opportunity to take a special course in which one chooses a supervisor and works on an independent, original research project with them, usually a part of the supervisor's active research that they deem is at the correct level for an advanced undergrad student to assist with. The student then gives a presentation in their relevant department colloquium when they've finished the bulk of their work, and the final grade was based on this as well as a written thesis. The student would then receive, for example, a B.Sc. with Honours, considered a pre-requisite for almost all M.Sc. and Ph.D. programs.

Anyway, I took part in this program at my school. For various reasons, most prominent of which was my lack of work ethic, my research project was essentially pushed to the wayside in favor of other courses, and there was a palpable sense of frustration (from both parties) whenever I would meet with my supervisor to discuss my progress.

I managed to put together a decent presentation (according to my supervisor and other audience members), and I received a fine grade for the course, but my relationship with my supervisor was irreparably spoiled at this point.

I've since decided that I'd like to be a high school math teacher, but the whole honours course, and the struggles that came with it, have been on my mind lately. Would it be considered rude, strange, or a waste of their time for me to email my supervisor and express my regret to them? I'm not sure what I'd say to them, but I can't help but feel that I should say something.

Comment: This is just me - I would move on.

Comment: I think a brief, polite email saying that, in hingsight, you regret the side-effects of your immaturity and the stress it may have caused your supervisor, and thank them for their patience. Such things tend to brighten one's day, believe me.